# Change third-party application name in Django

Tags: python, django

I use third-party application (django-flatblocks) in my Django project. How can i change the name of the application in admin interface (grappelli)? I need russian name. I already tried to create localization files (.po.mo) and it is work fine in some parts of admin interface, but in breadcrumbs do not. I think grappelli does not use translation in some templates and the best way to resolve the problem is to replace django-flatblocks verbose_name in apps.py "on the fly". Can i do it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the official documentation did. The solution is so simple: [For application users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors)

To quote the Manual:

> If you’re using “Rock ’n’ roll” in a project called anthology, but you
>   want it to show up as “Jazz Manouche” instead, you can provide your
>   own configuration:

```
# anthology/apps.py

from rock_n_roll.apps import RockNRollConfig

class JazzManoucheConfig(RockNRollConfig):
    verbose_name = "Jazz Manouche"

# anthology/settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'anthology.apps.JazzManoucheConfig',
    # ...
]
```

Comment: what if the 3rd-party app does not have an `apps.py` file / config?

Comment: Doesn't matter about the name of the file, as per the link, somewhere they will subclass AppConfig to create their own config, just find that Which does that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#for-application-authors